# Which Mobile Browser User Agent string starts with HTTP?

Tags: php, regex, mobile, browser, user-agent

***Disclaimer:*** I don't want to discuss if it's good or bad to use User Agent sniffing to detect Mobile Browsers!

There's a widely adopted RegEx (regular Expression) to detect a Mobile Browser by its User Agent string that you can download [from a site like this](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/).

And it contains a group `/ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)/i` matching a string starting with "HTTP".

Thus a bot or service using the PHP Pear module `HTTP_Request2` using a string like `HTP_Request2/2.1.1 (http://pear.php.net/package/http_request2) PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.15` would be detected as Mobile Browser and redirected to the websites mobile URL.

**Question:** What mobile browser is detected that way? What would that User Agent string of that mobile browser look like? (bonus: What needs to be changed to not match `HTTP_Request2` but the Mobile Browser?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it matches `http://www.voxtel.ru/UAProf/Voxtel_*.xml` for some reason, and that is all I could see that start with `http`.  You can see them in the [useragents.txt](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/devices.tar.gz) file from that site.  There are many others that contain `http` or `HTTP` later in the string though.

You could probably change the pattern, as I wouldn't rely on `http` somewhere in the user-agent string to determine if it's a mobile device:

```
/ht(c(-| |_|a|g|p|s|t))/i
```

Comment: OMG! I was looking for that file with all the User Agents. I didn't expect it to be on the About page. How could I know. ;) Thanks, mate! And thanks for the changed pattern!